# jQuery href attribute addition visible in Firebug but not in the source code

Tags: javascript, jquery

It may be trivial, but I have following code that is  dynamically adding some `href` attributes to an `<a>` element, with important variables that are passed to php generated page in a pop-up window.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    

   var url = jQuery("a.special-links").attr("href");
   var data = "?iframe=true&width=800&height=350&format=popup";

   jQuery("a.special-links").attr("href", url + data);
});
```

When inspected the page with Firebug, the `<a>` element got the url `href` properties right, but link does not work. When I inspect the code looking at source code, I see that `href` data part was in fact not added!

Is this runtime problem or something else ? Thanks for clues...

Comment: The source code won't reflect any changes made after the page downloads. The changes will be visible in a DOM inspector (Firebug).

Comment: When I (in Firefox) apply this jQuery statement to a random anchor element with the specified class it works.  Do you have your anchor tag disabled?  Do you have some funky base url that is the default url in that anchor element?  Do you have any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Your code is fine, see this [Fiddle Example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/LfMq3/). Your problem is on another portion of your code! Elaborate your end goal and better assistance will be provided.

Comment: Thanks, i did not mention i have colorbox jQuery plugin attached to this link. It is a kind of conflict, "runtime" issue. I ended up adding the href part str_replace-ing it from php, so i insure it is added very early! Thanks all! Sorry for misguide. X(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do no see the changes when you view source of the page because when you `view source` you are viewing the actual HTML document that was downloaded by the browser when you loaded the visited the URL. This can NEVER be changed by javascript.

When you write javascript you change something called the `Document Object Model` aka the `DOM`. This is an in memory data structure built by the browser as a result of parsing the HTML document. This is what firebug enables you to inspect.

Comment: Ahhh of course, thanks, this is the answer. But my links still do not work even if sintax is ok...